# Insert column with date in $request laravel

Tags: php, laravel, date, controller

I work on Laravel 5.2 and I have a form submitted in Ajax to insert data in a table.
This is my function in the controller :

```
public function saveChange(Request $request) {
            if($request->ajax()) {
                    Affectationabc::create($request->all());
                    return response()->json([
                            'testdata' => $request->all()
                    ]);
            }
    }
```

And I want to add at the same time the first day of current year and the last day in 2 others columns.

I tried to do something like this :

```
public function saveChange(Request $request) {
            if($request->ajax()) {
                    $firstDay = date('l',strtotime(date('Y-01-01')));
                    $lastDay = date('l',strtotime(date('Y-12-31')));
                    $request->merge(array('HISTO_AFFECT_DATE_DEB' => $firstDay, 'HISTO_AFFECT_DATE_FIN' => $lastDay));
                    Affectationabc::create($request->all());
                    return response()->json([
                            'testdata' => $request->all()
                    ]);
            }
    }
```

But It doesn't works, probably because of the format of the date. My columns HISTO_AFFECT_DATE_DEB and HISTO_AFFECT_DATE_FIN are dates in format Y-m-d.

How can I do this please ?

**EDIT:**

Maybe there is a problem in my Model, this is my code :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Affectationabc extends Model
{
protected $table = "Histo_AFFECT_ABC";
protected $primaryKey = 'HISTO_AFFECT_ID';

const CREATED_AT = 'HISTO_AFFECT_DATE_CREA';
const UPDATED_AT = 'HISTO_AFFECT_DATE_MAJ';

protected $dates = ['HISTO_AFFECT_DATE_CREA','HISTO_AFFECT_DATE_MAJ','HISTO_AFFECT_DATE_DEB','HISTO_AFFECT_DATE_FIN'];

protected function getDateFormat()
{
    return 'Y-m-d';
}


protected $fillable =  [
    'HISTO_AFFECT_ID_CATEG',
    'HISTO_AFFECT_ID_PERSONNEL',
    'HISTO_AFFECT_DATE_DEB',
    'HISTO_AFFECT_DATE_FIN',
    'HISTO_AFFECT_COMMENTAIRES',
    'HISTO_AFFECT_DATE_CREA',
    'HISTO_AFFECT_DATE_MAJ'
];


public function setHistoAffectDateDebAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['HISTO_AFFECT_DATE_DEB'] = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $value)->format('Y-m-d') ;
}

public function setHistoAffectDateFinAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['HISTO_AFFECT_DATE_FIN'] = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $value)->format('Y-m-d') ;
}
}
```

**EDIT2 :** It seems I have an error 500 when I try to add this dates !

Comment: $firstDay = date('Y-01-01'); and $lastDay = date('Y-12-31'); should work

Answer (score 1):

You didn't tell anything about what error do you get, but if it's date related, try to use [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/):

```
$firstDay = Carbon::now()->startOfYear()->format('Y-m-d');
$lastDay = Carbon::now()->endOfYear()->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Yes sorry but I see nothing, I just see that the request is not executed correctly because there is no new enbtry...

Comment: You can check for last error message in `storage\logs\laravel.log`. Did you try to use the code from my answer?

Comment: I found the solution, your code works perfectly but I had in my controller 2 functions which set this values before registration and made a conflict, I deleted them

Comment: In my Model* not in my Controller sorry

Answer (score 0):

I had this 2 functions in my Model that created conflicts :

```
public function setHistoAffectDateDebAttribute($value)
{
$this->attributes['HISTO_AFFECT_DATE_DEB'] = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $value)->format('Y-m-d') ;
}

public function setHistoAffectDateFinAttribute($value)
{
$this->attributes['HISTO_AFFECT_DATE_FIN'] = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $value)->format('Y-m-d') ;
}
```

I deleted them and I did this in my controller :

```
public function saveChange(Request $request) {
            if($request->ajax()) {
                    $firstDay = Carbon::now()->startOfYear()->format('Y-m-d');
                    $lastDay = Carbon::now()->endOfYear()->format('Y-m-d');
                    $request->merge(array('HISTO_AFFECT_DATE_DEB' => $firstDay, 'HISTO_AFFECT_DATE_FIN' => $lastDay));
                    Affectationabc::create($request->all());
                    return response()->json([
                            'testdata' => dd($request->all())
                    ]);
            }
    }
```

And everything works perfectly! I found the error in logs, thanks all !